# SNS service does not send SMS V3 API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I tried to use the V2 API to send SMS in the SNS service, and it worked, but it obligated me to create a topic and a subscription with the cellphone number target.

The documentation tells that i am not obligated to create a topic and subscription for the destination cellphone number to send SMS, so i discovered that i must use V3 API to send SMS without TopicARN obligation.

After to use a PHP server with 5.5 version, and V3 API, the TOPIC ARN was not asked, but it took so much time, more than 1 minute, and i got the 503 error as server response, there is no error on log_error.
Could you try to help me?

The code i used and worked on V2 but not V3:

```
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

$snsClient = SnsClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'mykey',
    'secret' => 'mysecret',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2'
));


$destination = array('+number'); // this way works on V2, but not on V3
//$destination = '+number'; // tried like this too

 try {
     $resp = $snsClient->publish(array(
        'PhoneNumber' => $destination,
        'Message' => utf8_encode('Message')
     ));



     echo $resp->get('MessageId');

 } catch(Exception $e)
 {
     echo $e->getMessage(); // I didn´t get exception, i got server error 503
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, after the start to use the PHP API V3 i must start like this:

```
$snsClient = SnsClient::factory(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'mykey',
        'secret'  => 'mysecret',
    )
));
```

But i still with problems, i receive this message:

Error executing "Publish" on "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: Sender InvalidPara (truncated...) InvalidParameter (client): Invalid parameter: TopicArn or TargetArn Reason: no value for required parameter - Sender InvalidParameter Invalid parameter: TopicArn or TargetArn Reason: no value for required parameter

I didn´t set up the TopicARN or TargetARN because i don´t want to create a subscription for each target number, and the documentation tells me that i can send for a number without register it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When sending SMS you don't need TopicArn. Just do like this:

First install **aws/aws-sdk-php**. Using composer:

`composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`

Create a php file with:

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'YOUR_KEY_HERE',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_HERE',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest'
);
$sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

$args = array(
    "SenderID" => "SenderName",
    "SMSType" => "Transational",
    "Message" => "Hello World! Visit www.tiagogouvea.com.br!",
    "PhoneNumber" => "FULL_PHONE_NUMBER"
);

$result = $sns->publish($args);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

The result must have one array with many data, including MessageId.

Comment: This solution works, but make sure you have `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*"` in your compose.json (as it fails cryptically with v2).